Setting a box on the stairs
Bob is carrying a solid, heavy, sealed box of uniform density up a long flight of uniform steps. He'd like to take a break halfway and set the box down, but each of the box's dimensions is more than twice the depth of a step - Bob can't simply set the box down as he would on the floor and let go, or else it will tumble down the stairs:

Is there any way for Bob to set the box down on the stairs and let go completely without it falling? What properties of the box or stairs make it possible?
This question is inspired by everyday life, no unusual materials or physical properties or anything out of the ordinary is needed - just a regular box and regular stairs. The box cannot be opened or reshaped or its contents shifted, and Bob has no helpers, or other materials like glue or nails at his disposal. Bob's arms are tired, and he just wants to set the box down as quickly as possible.

Bob can stand the box like this:

 Assuming the stair is angled at 45° as shown.
 Bob turns the box so that its smallest dimension is left-to-right as originally seen.

 At A the corner of the box sits just near the edge of the stair.
 At B the box rests against the edge of the stair.
 At C the box is not quite touching the edge of the stair.

 The centre of gravity of the box is vertically between A and B.
 If the box is a cube, Bob can use one finger to stop it tipping.

Edit:

 To be clear about the positioning of the box: the topmost corner (and the C of G) must be slightly to the left of the bottom corner A, vertically. The box is supported at B by the next step, and is only slightly off the balance point to stop it tipping to the left and overcoming friction at A.

 Here is a more accurate picture:


 The property of the stair and the box that makes it possible, is that the angle of the stair plus the angle between the box's diagonal and the side AB must be < 90°.


Nice solution, essentially same as mine, which, for some reason, I deleted ... rot13(phor) is clearly the corner case :)

In most real boxes the center of gravity will be lower than half the height, but maybe not by enough for it to matter.

Clearly, if the box can't stand up straight, then

 the box must be leaning at an angle, like so.


What we need is for

 1) the bottom corner to be touching the stair, so the box doesn't slide, and
 2) the box's center of gravity to be laterally between the bottom corner and the riser of the next stair.


 We check these conditions by tilting the box such that the bottom corner rests as close to the edge of the stair as possible. If the box's center of gravity is too far up the stairs, straightening the box will fix this. If the box's center is too far down the stairs, then 1) is unsatisfiable on these stairs and Bob is out of luck.


See this image for the general idea (imagine there are more than 1 step):

 

The ways that the box touches the stairs are as follows:

 it touches one step at one point of contact; it touches the next higher step(s) with one line of contact (each).

If the dimensions of the box are

 $a\le b\le c$

and each step on the stairs has

 depth $d$ and height $h$

then it is possible, assuming that the surfaces have enough friction, to set the box down if

 $$\frac{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}{a} \ge\frac{h}{d}$$

by considering the centre of mass of the box and

 the left hand side is the "toppling ratio" of the box, while the right hand side is the "step ratio"

The worst case is

 $a=b=c$, so left hand side is $\sqrt2$, we have that

on stairs satisfying the following property, any box can be set down on it

 $h \le \sqrt2 d$.


Just curious and trying to imagine: is the box then touching the stairs edge in one point or in one line?

@FirstNameLastName added explanation in second spoiler

rot13(ner, ba ybjre fgrc, gjb cbvagf bs pbagnpg fbzrgvzrf be nyjnlf be arire cbffvoyr?)

@FirstNameLastName fixed some algebra mistakes. If you want a line of contact on the bottom stair as well, then you need stricter requirements. In the worst case, $h<d$ should work for any box.

rot13(V gehyl ncbybtvmr gb nfx, ohg, V jbaqrerq, pna bar fyvqr lbhe fbyhgvba xrrcvat hccre fgrcf gbhpuvat n yvar hagvy ybjrfg fgrc nyfb gbhpurf n yvar ... V gevrq znahnyyl jvgu zl tynffrf pnfr ba zl pbzchgre zbavgbe fgnaq, naq vg frrzrq gb or cbffvoyr, ohg gura, gung boivbhfyl vf whfg gbb zhpu reebe cebar be whfg cynva jebat.)

Don't worry about asking. Probably not if it is already close to toppling to begin with, since then the centre of mass will overhang the line of contact. To be more precise, I guess I could have addressed issues about the coefficient of friction.

If Bob's arms are tired, he can give them a rest by

 placing the box on a stair in an unstable configuration

and standing

 on a lower step, leaning lightly against the box to stabilize it

like so:

 

Arguably this could or could not count as "let go completely", as some contact is still needed, but it will take the stress off his arms and reduce the forces he needs to assert significantly.

Just for reference I un-delete (rather quickly given) answer which, for some reason, I had deleted. It is essentially same as @WeatherVane's answer (which I full-hearted support).
If you manage to position cuboid

 4 sides parallel to stairs (seen as points from side view)

giving extreme case (side view) : a cube (here side length 2)

 

then no matter what 'dimensions' the cuboid box has:

 if (side view) side to the left is longer than (or equal to) side to the right, then center of gravity is left (side view) or equal to point of contact (contact being on, or left to, edge) and you may try to proceed ...

In terms of everyday life properties of the box and uniform stairs (here 'length' 1):

 deviating more from perfect cube (which is perhaps property OP is asking for) will, in practice, as mover rule of thumb, certainly be safer :)

In terms of mathematics:

 perhaps one needs to formally prove that deviating from proposed solution always leads to more instability in terms of 'sliding off' or 'leaning over'.

